# UncheckAll / Check a checkbox when another checkbox is checked overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, dhtmlx

I have dropdown checkboxes with function where if I click on an checkbox named `'ALL'` its will deselect all other selected checkbox, its working but when I try to do the other way around where on select checkboxes other than `'ALL'` it will deselect only `'ALL'` checkbox, it overlap with my first function, it does the job, but the `'ALL'` checkbox doesn't selected can anyone help me with this, any help is much appreciated.

Below is my code :

HTML :

```
<label class="text-primary" for="type">Type: </label>
                        <select id="type" mode="checkbox" style="width: 300;">
                            <option value="ALL" selected="Selected" checked="1">ALL</option>
                            <option value="Car">Car</option>
                            <option value="Ball">Ball</option>
                            <option value="Radio">Radio</option>
                        </select>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
type_combobox.attachEvent("onCheck", function(value, state){
        var values = type_combobox.getChecked();
        type_value = {};// put combo value into scope variable
        for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
            type_value[values[i]] = true;// build hash for easy check later
        }
        //UNCHECK CHECKBOXES IF ALL IS SELECTED
        if(type_value['ALL'] == true){
            type_combobox.forEachOption(function(optId){
                type_combobox.setChecked(optId.index,false);
            })
            type_combobox.setChecked(0,true);
        }
        gantt.render();// and repaint gantt
    });

    //InCORRECT
        if(type_value['ALL'] == true && !type_value['ALL'] == false){
            type_combobox.setChecked(0,false);
        }
```

Comment: You're using 'select' not 'input check' , what's you're main goal here? you want to use 'select multipe options' or just use 'input type checks' ?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps, I think this works as you expect:

```js
$(function(){

function unCheckAll() {

  $(".myCheckGroup").each(function(index) {
  if ($(this).attr('name') != 'all')
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
})
}

$(".myCheckGroup").change(function() {
  let chk = this;
  let isChecked = $(this).is(':checked')
  console.log(chk.name)
  if (chk.name == 'all') {
      unCheckAll()
  }else {
    $('.myCheckGroup[name=all]').prop('checked', false);
  }
})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="all" value="all" class="myCheckGroup">all</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="one" value="1" class="myCheckGroup">one</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="two" value="2" class="myCheckGroup">two</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="thee" value="3" class="myCheckGroup">three</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="four" value="4" class="myCheckGroup">four</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Jordi, thanks for your help, this would works but unfortunately not for my dhtmlx `onCheck` function. same principles but the code need to be different a little, if you can help me with it, it would great thanks